# key_load_public: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh

I have a problem on my Ubuntu server. When I try to ssh from that server to a second server, I get this error:

```
federico@federico:~/.ssh$ ssh root@federicolivieri.noip.me -vvv
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/federico/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "federicolivieri.noip.me" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to federicolivieri.noip.me [95.144.54.179] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <html><head>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <title>400 Bad Request</title>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </head><body>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <h1>Bad Request</h1>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </p>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <hr>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: <address>Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>

debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: </body></html>

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

However I can see the id_rsa under /home/federico/.ssh/

```
federico@federico:~/.ssh$ ls -l
total 76
-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico  1265 Jun 29 14:10 config
-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico  3261 Jun 22 09:59 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico   727 Jun 22 09:59 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico 11906 Jul 19 09:28 known_hosts.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico  9682 Jun 30 09:04 known_hosts.old
```

I research for that error but everyone suggest something different and those solutions didn't work for me. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: it seems Apache is answering to port 22/TCP (the SSH port)

Comment: `<title>400 Bad Request</title>` This does not look like a SSH server.

Answer (score 0):

-rw-r--r-- 1 federico federico  3261 Jun 22 09:59 id_rsa

You have to have your key read protected.

chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa

Comment: I don't think that's going to help this problem, when Apache appears to be listening on port 22...

Comment: `debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/federico/.ssh/id_rsa type -1`

Have you tried to [nmap](https://nmap.org/) host?